# During the last supper, was it obvious to the disciples that Judas was the one who would betray Jesus?

Tags: matthew

NIV Matthew 26:

> 20 When evening came, Jesus was reclining at the table with the Twelve. 21And while they were eating, he said, “Truly I tell you, one of you will betray me.”
>
> 22They were very sad and began to say to him one after the other, “Surely you don’t mean me, Lord?”
>
> 23Jesus replied, “The one who has dipped his hand into the bowl with me will betray me. 24The Son of Man will go just as it is written about him. But woe to that man who betrays the Son of Man! It would be better for him if he had not been born.”
>
> 25Then Judas, the one who would betray him, said, “Surely you don’t mean me, Rabbi?”
>
> Jesus answered, “You have said so.”

Was it obvious to the disciples that Judas was the one who would betray Jesus at this point in time? Why or why not?

Comment: There was other evidence. John reports the fact (not suspicion) of Judas' thieving from the bag. The lists of disciples in the synoptics indicate some unsettlement in the pairings of Judas with others. Judas' accusation of the woman who anointed Jesus. The fact that Judas had no spiritual questions to ask of Jesus when others (even Philip) did so. Up-voted +1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "NO".  We have this record in John 13:26-30 -

> Jesus answered, “It is the one to whom I give this morsel after I have
> dipped it.” Then He dipped the morsel and gave it to Judas son of
> Simon Iscariot. And when Judas had taken the morsel, Satan entered
> into him.
>
> Then Jesus said to Judas, “What you are about to do, do quickly.”
> **But no one at the table knew why Jesus had said this to him**. Since Judas kept the money bag, **some thought that Jesus was telling him to
> buy what was needed** for the feast, or to give something to the poor.
> 30As soon as he had received the morsel, Judas went out into the
> night.

Thus, the disciples appeared ignorant of what was goin on despite hearing the whole conversation and seeing what Jesus did.